# Upload form with image and nsstrings to PHP file

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsstring, http-post

I am trying to send form data which has a image and 2 `nsstrings` to a php file and I want to send `uiimage`.image with the name of "document" and one `nsstring` with the name of "name" and another `nsstring` with the name of "userid".

Here is my code so far.

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Myimage.image, 1.0);
                if (imageData != nil)
                {
                    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name];      //set name here
                    NSLog(@"%@", filename);
                    NSString *urlString = @"http://URL/upload.php";
                    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
                    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
                    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

                    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[filename dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [request setHTTPBody:body];
                    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
                    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
                    NSLog(@"finish");
}
```

Comment: you can do using afnetworking which it is easy to use for upload.

Comment: Can you please ad some sample code or any reference about afnetworking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Afnetworking 3.0

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"your server url" parameters:@{@"parameter_1":@"string 1",@"parameter_2":@"string 2"} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            if (image) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) name:imagename fileName:@"recipeImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }

        }error:nil];

        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [manager
                      uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                      progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          });
                      }
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[[error valueForKey:@"userInfo"] valueForKey:@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);// your response here
                              callback(YES,responseObject);
                          }
                      }];

        [uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this one and i will let you know.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

NSString *imageBase64 = [dataImage base64forData];

- (NSString*)base64forData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[self bytes];
    NSInteger Datalength = [self length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((Datalength + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < Datalength; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < Datalength) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < Datalength ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < Datalength ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


}
```